# Performance of IPX/SPX and TCP/IP

Tags: performance, network-programming, tcp, protocols, network-protocols

I understand that IPX and SPX both provide connection services similar to TCP/IP. Here, IPX is similar to IP and SPX is similar to TCP and hence eager to know about this.

How does the performance of IPX/SPX exceed that of TCP in LAN ?
Why is IPX/SPX not used in LAN alone if its performance is superior to that of TCP in the case of LAN ?

I searched the internet and landed up in few links but it did not seem to convey some clear reasons for this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPX/SPX . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IPX was optimized for LANs. For one thing, IPX addresses are formed using an Ethernet MAC addresses and a 32-bit network ID. This design allowed for "zero configuration" of the IPX nodes in most cases - just plug computer in and it's on the network. IPv6 with stateless autoconf has the same properties, btw.

SPX (analogue of TCP) was also highly optimized for LANs. For example, it had per-packet nacks instead of per-octet acks in TCP without any explicit window management functions. That allowed file servers to be very simple - just spew file contents into the Ethernet at the top speed. If a client misses a packet then you can re-read it from disk/cache and re-send it.

In contrast, with TCP you have to buffer all the unacknowledged data and re-send all of the data in the send buffer after a lost packet (in case you don't use selective acknowledgment feature).

However, IPX was not suitable for the WANs at all. For example, it couldn't cope with different frame sizes. I.e. two networks with different frames (say, Ethernet and Ethernet with jumbo frames) couldn't interoperate without a proxy server or some form of encapsulation.

Additionally, packet reordering on WANs is ubiquitous but it plays hell with SPX (at least with Novell's implementation) causing a lot of spurious NAKs.

And of course, IPX addresses were not hierarchical so not very suited for routing. Network ID in theory could be used for this, but even large IPX/SPX deployments were not complex enough to develop rich routing infrastructure.

Right now, IPX is interesting only as a historical curiosity and in maintenance of a small number of VERY legacy systems.

Comment: This makes in very useful in certain automation applications. For instance a PC based controller using AutomationDirect.com field I/O.

Comment: Network addresses in TCP/IP can be aggregated i.e router have to keep only little information but so is not the case with IPX/SPX.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a critical distinction between SPX/IPX and TCP/IP. TCP/IP is the basis of the Internet. SPX/IPX is not.

SPX/IPX was an interesting protocol, but is now of interest only within a given corporation.

---

It's often the case in the real world that something technically superior loses due to business reasons. Consider [Betamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betamax) video tape format vs. [VHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhs). Betamax was considered technically superior, yet you can't buy a Betamax recorder today except maybe on eBay. One may argue that Windows won over Macintosh, despite the fact that the MacOS user interface was much nicer, due entirely to business decisions (mainly the decision by Apple not to permit clones).

Similarly, issues far beyond the control of Xerox destroyed SPX/IPX as a viable protocol - HTTP runs over TCP/IP, not over SPX/IPX. HTTP rules the world, therefore TCP/IP rules the world.

SPX/IPX has been left as an exercise for the reader.

---

BTW, I've been talking about SPX/IPX as though they were a Xerox protocol - not quite. They are a Novell protocol, but based on the [Xerox Network System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Network_Systems) protocols. Interestingly, I found nothing about this protocol on the web site either of Xerox nor of Novell.

Also, see the Wikipedia article on [IPX/SPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPX/SPX).

Comment: True. The SPX/IPX protocol is not popular in Wide Area Network and Internet, but it is superior to TCP in LAN. Hence eager to know the reasons for it.

Comment: @Karthik: the reasons for what? The main reason for the failure of SPX/IPX is the success of the Internet, which used TCP/IP. That completely supersedes any technical advantages that SPX/IPX may enjoy. The technical advantages are totally irrelevant.

Comment: So, Is it just because HTTP opted for using TCP/IP, the IPX/SPX got obsoleted ? But, aren't there any technical reasons that hindered IPX/SPX from being good for Wide Area Network or Internet ?

Comment: @Karthik: I don't know the history on that. I do recall that HTTP (and the Web) was built on top of the ArpaNet, which used TCP/IP. The rest, as they say, was history. You'd have to do quite a bit of research to determine whether Xerox ever made any attempt to require that the Internet should run on either protocol.

Comment: @Karthik: Also, keep in mind that, when it started, the Internet was quite a modest thing. I remember my first sight of amazon.com. I scoffed at a coworker who was actually going to allow his credit card number to go across the Internet to actually _buy_ some books! I thought he was crazy. Today, we think nothing of doing financial transactions and everything else over the Internet. I bet if Xerox had known that would happen, they'd have fought for parity.

Comment: @John Saunders : I think, it has be be checked with Xerox too.

Comment: @Karthik: _what_ has to be checked with Xerox?

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage of the TCP/IP Protocol stack is a lower speed than IPX/SPX. However, the TCP/IP stack is now also used in local networks to simplify the negotiation of local and wide area network protocols. Currently, it is considered the main one in the most common operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

IPX/SPX can coexist on a lan with TCP/IP. PC's that wish to be isolated from the web can still share files/printers by using IPX and not loading TCP. This is more secure than any firewall and second only to cutting wires.

Answer (score -2):

IPX/SPX performed better than TCP/IP back in the day, on systems where you could compare the two.  That is no longer true since TCP got all the developer effort from about 1993 onwards because of HTTP.

Essentially, IPX/SPX was obsoleted by TCP/IP, and so it is no longer relevant.  Maintaining two sets of protocols is too much effort for network operators, so the less capable one dies out.  Eventually this will happen to IPv4.

Comment: Is it just because HTTP opted for using TCP/IP, the IPX/SPX got obsoleted ? But, aren't there any technical reasons that hindered IPX/SPX from being good for Wide Area Network or Internet ?

Comment: SPX never performed better than TCP, because of no windowing. In fact SPX never really worked at all, because of no orderly close. By the time they fixed it in SPX-2 it was already game over.

Comment: The least capable protocols aren't always the ones to die out.  There are all manner of reasons, practical and political, that can cause a superior solution to be abandoned.